# Get text of a custom entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I've made a custom entry, but the problem is: now i dont know how to get the text from this component, the entry x:name.text isn't working

i've tried to put this in the custom class, but no success:

```cs
    public new string Text
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
                set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
            }
```

My contentpage.cs:

```cs
    async void LoginUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameEntry.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordEntry.Text))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameEntry.Text))
                        await DisplayAlert("Usuario", "Digite o Usuario", "OK");
                    else
                        await DisplayAlert("Senha", "Digite a Senha", "OK");
                    return;
                }
```

My XAML file:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:HCTaNaMao.Customs"
             x:Class="HCTaNaMao.Views.Login" >   
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,100,0,0">
            <Image Source="HCbackground.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="200" />
            <Label Text="Usuario" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <custom:CustomEntry
                                x:Name=" usernameEntry"
                                CornerRadius="18"
                                IsCurvedCornersEnabled="True"
                                BorderColor="LightBlue"    
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                FontSize="17"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                Placeholder="Usuário"
                                PlaceholderColor="LightGray"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                WidthRequest="100"/>
            <Label Text="Senha"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <custom:CustomEntry
                                x:Name=" passwordEntry"
                                CornerRadius="18"
                                IsCurvedCornersEnabled="True"
                                BorderColor="LightBlue"    
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                FontSize="17"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                Placeholder="Senha"
                                PlaceholderColor="LightGray"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                WidthRequest="100"
                                IsPassword="True"/>

            <Button Text="Entrar" TextColor="White" Clicked="LoginUser" WidthRequest="110" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="SteelBlue" BorderRadius="20"/>
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My custom class:

```cs
    public class CustomEntry : Entry
        {
            public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(BorderColor),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(CustomEntry),
                Color.Gray);

            // Gets or sets BorderColor value
            public Color BorderColor
            {
                get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
                set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
            }


            public static readonly BindableProperty BorderWidthProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(BorderWidth),
                typeof(int),
                typeof(CustomEntry),
                Device.OnPlatform<int>(1, 2, 2));

            // Gets or sets BorderWidth value
            public int BorderWidth
            {
                get { return (int)GetValue(BorderWidthProperty); }
                set { SetValue(BorderWidthProperty, value); }
            }


            public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(CornerRadius),
                typeof(double),
                typeof(CustomEntry),
                Device.OnPlatform<double>(6, 7, 7));

            // Gets or sets CornerRadius value
            public double CornerRadius
            {
                get { return (double)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
                set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
            }


            public static readonly BindableProperty IsCurvedCornersEnabledProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(IsCurvedCornersEnabled),
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(CustomEntry),
                true);

            // Gets or sets IsCurvedCornersEnabled value
            public bool IsCurvedCornersEnabled
            {
                get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCurvedCornersEnabledProperty); }
                set { SetValue(IsCurvedCornersEnabledProperty, value); }
            }

            public new string Text
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
                set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
            }
```

the usernameEntry.Text is coming null

```cs
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: What happens if you don't add the new Text property to your control? Is Text still null?

Comment: If I use a common entry I can get the text by x:name.Text

Comment: Entry already has a Text property, so you should not need to redefine it for a control that inherits from Entry

Comment: But how can I get the text tho?

Comment: @Reinaldo, As Jason said CustomEntry already has Text Property, so you just use `usernameEntry.Text` to get Text. When you run your project, usernameEntry.text is null, please enter some text in usernameEntry, so you can get this Text property.

Comment: @CherryBu the Text Property was just a failed try, the error occurs with or without the property. This is a Login Page, so I set the user text and password text, when I press the Login button, the usernameEntry is null, not the text

Comment: @Reinaldo, I do one sample according to your code, you can take a look, there is no issue at my side.https://github.com/851265601/CustEntryDe

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
  public new string Text
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
                set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
            }
```

Which shouldn't have the new tag.

But, Entry already has a Text Property, and you are extending the Entry class for your CustomEntry. so, to simply put, remove this:

```
  public new string Text
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
                set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
            }
```

and you will be able to do yourentry.Text just fine

Comment: Even without this I can't get the text, it was just a failed try

Comment: Are you setting the Text? What exception are you gettting? Is the Text null or the Entry is null?

Comment: The entry is null when I click on Login button

Comment: Well, so the problem isn't the Text property.... How are you declaring the entry??

Comment: I edited the main question, take a look in the XAML file